# How can I call Workbook_Open on Workbook A from Workbook B?

Tags: vba, excel, events

My situation is that I am trying to open Workbook A from Workbook B and run the Workbook_Open subroutine.  The issue with just simply using `Workbooks.Open("c:\myworkbook.xls")` is that I need to plant data in Workbook A before the `Workbook_Open` subroutine runs.

I have two ideas, neither of which I particularly like, so I was wondering if there was a better way.  My two ideas are as follows.

**Option 1: Open Workbook A with macros disabled, plant the data, save and close the workbook then re-open it with macros enabled.**  The reasons I would prefer not to do this is: I am dealing with a .xls file that has a fair amount of formatting (basically I am simulating how a human would use it thousands of times over) and saving the file thousands of times may cause the file to corrupt.  Additionally this takes a fair amount of time to open the workbook twice, and it does not seem at all efficient to me.  One of the big points of emphasis is speed and efficiency with the quickest turnaround time.

**Option 2: Duplicate the Workbook_Open code as a public subroutine in elsewhere within a module.**  This is the more desirable of the two, but the issue is I do not necessarily have permission to perform this action and doing this will involve plenty of red tape, red flags, etc.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
Workbooks("Workbook A").Application.Run (Workbooks("Workbook A").Workbook_Open)
```

Comment: Can you replace the values in workbook A with UDFs that are defined in workbook B?

Comment: You could consider injecting a small *Public* Sub into the `ThisWorkbook` module of Workbook A - you can call the Private `Workbook_Open` from that.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook_Open` is a private sub.  You cannot call it directly.

May I offer Option 3:  Copy the code from `Workbook_open` into a sub in Workbook B.  Then you can call it will be public and you can call it for your simulation.

In addition, if corruption is a concern, create a copy of Workbook A to use for your tests.  Then if it gets corrupted, the original will still be available.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I will probably head that route then, convoluted as it may be I think it will work out.  I definitely am not using our gold copy for all this testing!

Comment: `Workbook_Open` can be redefined as a public sub, no? (Not that I would, just for the sake of argument)

Comment: @RubberDuck I am horrified to discover that you are correct.  But this reverts the problem to changing the code with the OP's option 2.

Comment: Truly terrifying info. I know.

Answer (score 4):

From workbook B:

```
'add vb reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("BookA.xlsm")
    Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Public Sub Blah()"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "   Workbook_Open"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
    End With

    Application.Run "BookA.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.Blah"

End Sub
```

See:http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Good approach. I note that if the variables are defined as objects the reference to extensibility is unncessary,.