# How to handle error generated inside another workbook's Workbook_Open event?

Tags: vba, excel, exception

I have two workbooks in the same folder: `bkOpenErrorTest.xlsm` and `bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm`.

`bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm` has the following code in its `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Dim dict As Dictionary

Set dict = New Dictionary
dict.Add 0, 0
dict.Add 0, 0

End Sub
```

When this workbook is opened by double-clicking the filename, it throws the expected unhandled error:

```
This key is already associated with an element of this collection
```

`bkOpenErrorTest.xlsm` has the following code in Module1:

```
Sub testOpen()

Dim bk As Workbook

On Error GoTo errHandler

Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm"

Exit Sub

errHandler:
Debug.Print "reached error handler"

End Sub
```

When error trapping is set to `Break on Unhandled Errors`, and I run `testOpen()`, the unhandled error is still raised when `bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm` opens.  Why isn't the error caught by `testOpen()`'s error handler?  And how can I handle this error?  I have an application where I'd like to cycle through many workbooks in a folder that have buggy code like this in their `workbook_open()` event, and I can't iterate through them if the program crashes on an unhandled error like this.

Comment: You can try disabling events - unless you need the `Workbook_Open` event to run

Comment: @urdearboy thanks, that's a possibility, but i would like to trap errors selectively, so that e.g. if the workbook has trouble opening due to corruption, we would handle that error differently (e.g. by skipping that workbook in the loop)

Comment: If that is the specific error you are trying to overcome either use  the dictionary shorthand method that overwrites duplicates or more generally wrap potential errors in On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the error is not being handled is that the two processes are not in the same thread. If you were calling a 'helper' sub procedure from a main sub procedure, you remain in the same thread and errors thrown in the 'helper' are caught by error control in the main. This is akin to why an error in a procedure launched by Application.Run will not have thrown errors handled by the error control in the procedure that launched it.

To gain any measure of control over what happens in the newly opened workbook's Workbook_Open, you need to control things on the Application instance level. The following halts execution of the Workbook_Open event procedure; if it isn't necessary to process the code, then this could be your solution.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set bk = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsb")
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

If the Dictionary populating is the specific error you are trying to overcome use the dictionary shorthand method that overwrites duplicates.

```
Dim dict As Dictionary

Set dict = New Dictionary
dict.Item(0) = 0
dict.Item(0) = 1
'dict.count = 1 with key as 0 and item as 1
```

More generally you can wrap potential errors in On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0.

```
Dim dict As Dictionary

Set dict = New Dictionary
On Error Resume Next
dict.Add 0, 0
dict.Add 0, 1
On Error GoTo 0
'dict.count = 1 with key as 0 and item as 0
```

Comment: His problem is an unhandled error. I'm demonstrating two methods of bypassing the error per *'And how can I handle this error?'*

Comment: But he wants to handle it form bkOpenErrorTest.xlsm, not from bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm.

Comment: ... and when he comes to the realization that that is simply never going to happen, then he might consider these options.

Comment: Shouldn't you then in your answer inform him, that what he want's is never going to work?

Comment: Perhaps I will after I find time to set up multiple external workbooks and test every scenario and possible solution I can think of. For now, the fact that the spawned workbook is not in the same thread as the calling sub procedure is the reason that the calling sub procedure's error handling is not covering the error thrown in the new workbook.

Comment: I can't change the code programmatically in `bkOpenErrorTest_dict` because it crashes every time i open it.  And given that there are hundreds of workbooks to iterate through in my use case, manual code change is impractical.

Comment: @sigil - It crashes because you have events turned on. Turn them off to avoid the events, ***then*** change the code once you have a valid reference.

Comment: I'm going to go for this answer's recommendation of disabling event handling, as it seems that it's impossible to do anything else short of manually modifying the target workbook's code.

Answer (score 4):

The error is unhandled because the newly opened Workbook is running inside of what is basically an asychronous process - `Workbook_Open` is an *event handler*, so it is not being called from your code. It is being invoked as a callback function from inside whatever external Excel process is opening the document. You can demonstrate the same behavior with ***any*** event handler:

```
'In Sheet1
Sub Example()
    On Error GoTo Handler
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Foo"
    Exit Sub

Handler:
    Debug.Print "Handled"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
        Err.Raise 6
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need to bulk process the files, your only (easy) option is going to be disabling events before the call to open:

```
Sub testOpen()
    Dim bk As Workbook

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bkOpenErrorTest_dict.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Debug.Print "reached error handler"
End Sub
```

If for some reason it is vitally important that the buggy `Workbook_Open` runs, then you can use the solution [Tim Williams outlines here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871747/4088852). Just create a public wrapper function in the target workbook, then call that from within the context of your own error handler.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on Jeeped's answer, modifying the code in the target workbook is impractical because of the volume of workbooks that I need to address.

Comment: Then this answer should explain why what you want to do is impossible.  ;-)

Comment: @sigil Note also that you don't have to ***save*** the code you emit into the workbooks via the linked answer - you just have to ***call it***.

Comment: if the program crashes when the workbook opens, then the VBA-modifying code cannot be inserted in order to be run (as the program that would insert the code is no longer running).

Comment: @sigil Look at the code in the answer again. If you disable the events the `Workbook_Open` event ***won't run***, so it *can't* crash.