# How do you execute VBA script from a string?

Tags: vba

I want to execute a VBA command from a string.

Chr(34) = "

```
Application.Run ("'Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & "MsgBox (" & Chr(34) & "testy-test" & Chr(34) & ")" & vbCrLf & "End Sub'")
```

The sub in the middle of the above is simply

```
Sub foo()
MsgBox ("Testy-test")
End Sub
```

I realise there are far easier ways to do the above, but that's not what I'm after. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to attempt to do such a thing?

Comment: Why not? Curiosity.

Comment: [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) "runs a macro or calls a function" - not lines of code smushed together as a string.

Comment: Hence the question. Application.Eval and turning it into an object is also being wonky.

Comment: There's no "easy" mechanism like `Eval` in VBA, but you can do something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869616/how-can-i-call-workbook-open-on-workbook-a-from-workbook-b/27871747#27871747